# Как узнать объем свободной и занятой памяти

Tags: java, android

Как узнать объем свободной и занятой памяти Андроид устройства, то есть вывести это в переменную. Java, Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот есть способ:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void showStorageVolumes() {
    StorageStatsManager storageStatsManager = (StorageStatsManager) getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
    StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager) getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
    if (storageManager == null || storageStatsManager == null) {
        return;
    }
    List<StorageVolume> storageVolumes = storageManager.getStorageVolumes();
    for (StorageVolume storageVolume : storageVolumes) {
        final String uuidStr = storageVolume.getUuid();
        final UUID uuid = uuidStr == null ? StorageManager.UUID_DEFAULT : UUID.fromString(uuidStr);
        try {
            Log.d("AppLog", "storage:" + uuid + " : " + storageVolume.getDescription(this) + " : " + storageVolume.getState());
            Log.d("AppLog", "getFreeBytes:" + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(this, storageStatsManager.getFreeBytes(uuid)));
            Log.d("AppLog", "getTotalBytes:" + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(this, storageStatsManager.getTotalBytes(uuid)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // IGNORED
        }
    }
}
```

вот [ссылка](https://medium.com/cashify-engineering/how-to-get-storage-stats-in-android-o-api-26-4b92eca6805b) на первоисточник. В этом способе все в логи идет, но можно перенести в переменные которые вам нужно. Если что будет непонятно, не стесняйтесь и спрашивайте, постараемся помочь. Удачи :)